# Mapping an partial object to a destination object using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, object, automapper

I have this model class

```cs
  public class AppInfo
  {
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório")]
    public string nick { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório")]
    public string version { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public bool invalidated { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime releasedAt { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime createdAt { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime updatedAt { get; set; }
  }
```

and i have a put request that receives optionally three fields of the above model

```cs
  public class AppInfoPutModel
  {
    public string description { get; set; }
    public bool invalidated { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime releasedAt { get; set; }
  }
```

and when i receive the partial information in body request, i need to map these new informations
inside the object destination using AutoMapper or something similar and i tried to do this

```
    AppInfo appInfo = await_getAppInfoByNickAndVersionBll.GetAppInfoByNickAndVersion(appNick, appVersion);

    new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<AppInfoPutModel, AppInfo>());

    _mapper.ConfigurationProvider.CreateMapper();

    _mapper.Map(appInfoToUpdate, appInfo);

    await _putAppInfoBll.PutAppInfo(appInfo, appInfoToUpdate);

    return new OkObjectResult(appInfo);
```

and this code are throwing an error because the AppInfoPutModel doesn't have all the properties that AppInfo has, and cant map all of the field, is there any way to map just these 3 fields and keep the other fields?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to pass the actual result of mapping. This line:

```cs
_mapper.Map(appInfoToUpdate, appInfo);
```

Returns a result of mapping from the source object to the existing destination object. So, save the mapping result to a variable:

```cs
var mappedAppInfo = _mapper.Map(appInfoToUpdate, appInfo);
```

and then pass it to your service so changes made can be saved with EF:

```cs
await _putAppInfoBll.PutAppInfo(mappedAppInfo, appInfoToUpdate);
```

Final note: unless you do something else with the `appInfoToUpdate`, you don't need it for saving the changes made to the `AppInfo` entity. With the code you showed I don't see a reason why pass it over. Just save the changes made to `AppInfo`.

But let's go deeper! If the `AppInfo` entity is tracked, you don't need to pass it to the service too, just save the changes from DB context (assuming that your service just saves the changes to the database and does nothing more).

```cs
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Read more about EF tracking API in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking).